Is there a way to kill a specific activity whenever the user leaves it?
In developers setting, there's an option called "Don't keep activities". Is there an api in adb or a way to do this for a certain app?
The app doesn't actually run in background, as it doesn't show up in the "background check" list. So set RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore doesn't really work. What I'd like to achieve is that whenever I leave and come back, a new session is restarted instead of restoring the previous one.
Thanks!
Edit: Android version 14, Samsung One UI 6.0
